# deciphering htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a couple of rules mentioned in the htaccess that rewrites for the image path.
I wan to know what this rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]` doing for a request like `domain.com/7755-thickbox_default/portland-4-dining-table.jpg`
also is there any tool like regex101.com to decipher htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [htaccess.mwl.be](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

Note that asking for tools on StackOverflow is not considered a good practice.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you check it. I tried the htaccess.mwl.be, but it did not give me the expected output, thanks.